# php file submission failed

Tags: php

I used the codes(html+php script) below to upload image file

submit.html

```
<html> 
<body> 

<form action="upload_file.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
<label for="file">Filename:</label> 
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" /> 
<br /> 
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /> 
</form> 

</body> 
</html>
```

php upload file upload_file.php

```
<?php

echo $_FILES["file"]["type"] ;

echo  "<br>";
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000))
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";

    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }
?>
```

but it reported error:

```
image/jpeg
Upload: 02.jpg
Type: image/jpeg
Size: 54.2626953125 Kb
Temp file: /tmp/phpT617qx

Warning: move_uploaded_file(upload/02.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/virtual/site18/fst/var/www/html/test/upload_file.php on line 29

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpT617qx' to 'upload/02.jpg' in /home/virtual/site18/fst/var/www/html/test/upload_file.php on line 29
Stored in: upload/02.jpg
```

submit.html and upload_file.php are in same directory with mod 777

Welcome any comment

Comment: What are the permissions on `upload/`? Does the directory exist?

Comment: Thanks, you are right, I forgot to e create the directory, please open an answer, I will select it as correct answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are the permissions on `upload/`? Does the directory exist?

Answer (score 1):

It could be because you should assign correct permissions for writing files into that file.